# ICC inline assembler doesn`t like push/pop

Tags: inline-assembly, icc

I try to excute assembler inline with icc in msasm:

```
int main (void)
{
  __asm{
    mov eax, 5h;  //works
    push eax;     // after shell command /opt/intel/bin/icc -use_msasm asm.c:
                  // asm.c(7): (col. 5) error: Unsupported instruction form in asm                          
                  // instruction push.

   //pop ebp;    // the same 
        };

printf("success!\n");
return 1;
}
```

Does anybody know why icc doesn`t accept push and pop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In 64bit mode, `push <32bit-reg>` is undefined (`push` and `pop` always operate on an entire register, i.e. whether the operation is `PUSH AX`, `PUSH EAX` or `PUSH RAX` depends only on the current default operand size - to the CPU, the instruction/opcode is the same).

Comment: @FrankH. 16-bit push is always available (in all modes), but 64-bit mode can't use 32-bit push.  i.e. the 66h operand-size prefix works, but REX.W=0 doesn't override the default from 64 down to 32.  [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993)

Answer (score 1):

You should use x64 version of registers instead.
So the correct version should like this:

```
__asm{
    mov rax, 5h;
    push rax;
};
```

Also, pay attention to architecture differences when dealing with pointers, 0x8*******, etc. **You should never use batch Find and Replace without reading your inline first.**